# How to deserialize json into a c# class containing interface/abstract class properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a model that has a few properties one is an interface and one is abstract base class.  I have control of the server and client code.  Is there a way to deserialize the json into my model?  I have been using the JavaScriptSerializer class for encoding and decoding so a solution there would be nice but it doesnt have to be

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an instance of an abstract class so you can deserialize only to non abstract class, for example a derived class.

Comment: Thanks, MaxMun.  I suppose I should have made it clear that I want to instantiate the objects to legitimate concrete classes